# (MySQL) Get last data in every group (SubQuery)

Tags: mysql, subquery

Table:

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a5hOz.png)

Help me in. I'm suck in SubQuery. I wanna get the latest Name from every category group
Output:

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WGUGT.png)

I already search some reference in google and still didn't understand. Hopefully this time I can understand

Comment: Have you tried anything this is a very basic group query. Search for it you will certainly find a good tutorial. And no need for subquery at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use join on max_date for each category

```
select * from  
my_table m
inner join ( 
select category, max(date) max_date
from my_table
group by category) as t on m.date = t.max_date and m.category = t.category
```

Comment: @hansstfanus .. looking to your new image  ,, i have correclty change name to category ..

Answer (score 0):

Thx scaisEdge!!

I finally got it!
So this is my final query

```
select m.id, m.category, m.name, m.time  
from my_table m
inner join ( 
  select id, category, name, time
  from my_table
  order by id desc
) as t 
on m.id = t.id
group by category
```